# why ConfigurationManager not work on child project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

In a solution  I have three projects,you can see on picture.Want to access project-1 and project-2 from main project,use bellow syntax to show the desired project,but problem is when I try to find config file value show me error “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”
Note:individually each project work perfectly ,each project can fetch config file info with out showing any error.but they not work when goes from main project.

Need help get config file value on each project

**syntax use in main project**

```
using UI2;
using UI1;

      if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    UI1.Form1 fm = new UI1.Form1();
                    fm.Show();

                }
                if (radioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    UI2.Form1 fm = new UI2.Form1();
                    fm.Show();

                }
```

If have any query please ask,thanks in advanced.

[image]

Comment: if you added 2 other project to to main project reference,you do not must have any problem i try it with no error

Comment: irsog thanks for reply.hope you not try to get config file info.in my end it's also work fine,just fail to get config file info for each project,suppose i brows on project one from main project now i fail config file info in project-1.

Comment: When you run project WindowsFormsApplication1, all projects referenced reads configuration from WindowsFormsApplication1.exe.config, so just add your configuration key-value pairs in WindowsFormsApplication1's configuration file.

Comment: Jaska thanks for reply,is there any way to read config file on child project not in main project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also called your child classes by using "MSBuild" task.
for reference you can go to this page [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx)